# Understand traffic percent setting in Azure Function deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-appservice, azure-deployment-slots

I am trying to understand Azure Function deployment slot concept

1. What does the traffic % column represent? Even when my staging slot traffic % is set to 0, it's still getting triggered.
2. How does the scaling of nodes work for staging slot?

[image: azure function deployment slots]

Comment: Refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#route-production-traffic-automatically).

Answer (score 0):

> What does the traffic % column represent?

The ***Traffic %*** column in the `Function App deployment slots` refers to the `percentage of traffic` that is routed to that `particular slot`.

1. By default, `Traffic %` is set to `0` for the `newly created slot`, which means all the traffic is routed to the production slot and no traffic will be routed to the non-production/staging slot.
2. If you set `Traffic` setting as `20%` for `non-production slot`, the specified `%` of clients will be routed to the `non-production slot` and the remaining `80%` will be handled by the `production slot`.

[image]

The staging slot(**<app-name/slot-name>**) can be seen as a separate app with the same designation which works just like any other Function app.  Slot's configuration can be changed according to the requirement.

> Even when my staging slot traffic % is set to 0, it's still getting triggered.

1. Check the configuration of function app to make sure that all functions are referring to particular slot.
2. Try creating a new deployment slot and check if the issue persists.

> How does the scaling of nodes work for staging slot?

- The number of instances for the `staging slot/non-production slot` can be scaled independently.
- When you scale the number of instances for the `staging slot`, it will only affect the instances in that `slot` and `production slot` instances won't be affected. This helps to test the application with different scaling configurations.

[image]

**References:**

[Azure Functions deployment slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#manage-settings)